# Can I have two categories in one column in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

| id | name | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | shoes | Nike, Adidas, Jordan |

**How can I have multiple categories for "shoes" like the example up there. It doesn't mean to be separated with commas.
The table has to be in MySQL**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a mapping table with categories and products like each product id can be associated with multiple category ids and then at view time use MySQL group_concat function to get comma separated category names.

| ProductID | Category Id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

Use query as

```
Select products.title,group_concat(categories.title) as product_categories from products inner join 
product_categories on products.id=product_categories.product_id
inner join categories on product_categories.category_id=categories.id
group by products.id
```

Comment: Hey Ahmed Memon and how exactly can I fetch this data so I can use it

Comment: $result=$conn->query($sql);
 while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {  } This one is not working

Comment: Kindly mention the error if there is any.

Comment: "Undefined array key" when I'm trying to fetch the title of product_categories

Comment: I have updated the answer use product_categories as a key to getting the product categories from the updated query.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for many to many relationship.

You have to create 3 new tables,

Products(pid,...)

Categories(cid,...) and

Product_Category(pid,cid,..)

Where pid is a foreign key to Products table and category_id is a foreign key to Categories table.

Comment: The code @ahmed-memon wrote up there works but how can I fetch it tho. $result=$conn->query($sql); while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) { } This isn't working